# How to use Contains in LINQ to Entities with arbitrary property selection without evaluating an IQueryable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression, iqueryable

I'm trying to make a generic repository for entities that have a clear child-parent relation. F.e. AuditLogEntries with AuditLogs.

```cs
public class BaseWithParentRepository<TEntity, TKey, TParentKey> : BaseRepository<TEntity, TKey>, IRepositoryWithParent<TEntity, TKey, TParentKey> where TEntity : class, IDbEntityWithKey<TKey>, new()
{
    public Func<TEntity, TParentKey> ParentKeySelector { get; set; }

    public BaseWithParentRepository(IDbContext context, Func<TEntity, TParentKey> parentKeySelector) : base(context)
    {
        ParentKeySelector = parentKeySelector;
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> QueryByParentKey(TParentKey parentKey)
    {
        IEnumerable<TParentKey> parentIds = new TParentKey[] { parentKey };
        return Query.Where(e => parentIds.Contains(ParentKeySelector(e)));
    }
}
```

The AuditLogDetail class is:

```cs
public class AuditLogDetail : BaseDbEntity<Guid>
{
    public Guid AuditLogId { get; set; }
    public virtual AuditLog AuditLog { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string OldValue { get; set; }
    public string NewValue { get; set; }
}
```

The AuditLogDetails repository would be:

```cs
public class AuditLogDetailRepository : BaseWithParentRepository<AuditLogDetail, Guid, Guid>, IAuditLogDetailRepository
{
    public AuditLogDetailRepository(IDbContext context) : base(context, ald => ald.AuditLogId)
    {
    }
}
```

As you can see, the second parameter of the constructor for `BaseWithParentRepository` is a property selector, and the method `QueryByParentKey` tries to get all the AuditLogDetails of the parent entity (AuditLog).

However, when calling the `QueryByParentKey` method, the following exception is thrown:

```
Error: System.NotSupportedException: The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.NotSupportedTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.ContainsTranslator.TranslateContains(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression sourceExpression, Expression valueExpression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.ContainsTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<GetResults>b__1()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<GetResults>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__31_0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Manu.Data.BaseWithParentRepository`3.GetAllByParentKey(TParentKey parentKey)
```

I understand that calling `ParentKeySelector` inside `Contains` cannot be translated to SQL. So it seems that I should use `Expression<Func<TEntity, TParentKey>>` instead of `Func<TEntity, TParentKey>` to do what I want, but I don't know how to achieve my goal. Can somebody more familiar with Expressions please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the fact ParentKeySelector cannot be translate to SQL is the cause of the problem. Since it cannot be translate to SQL, it is then impossible to EF to convert the linq to SQL for execution by the DB server, not matter how you do it.

It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. However, if the parent/child relationship is explicit, you should be able to define foreign key references and have EF automatically resolve them automatically, see [EF tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx).

Comment: Alex W, I'm using code first and I have parent/child relationships working without any problem. However, I'm tired of having to write the same code to query the child entities and that is why I am trying to make a generic repository for the child entities. The problems arise when you try to do it in a generic way.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do now. One way to achieve that may be to just have the same name for the parentId, using the [Column("AuditLogId ")] to annotate the actual name in the DB. Defining a common interface with the ParentId column being shared by all child classes.  Then your query can simply be Query.Where(e => e.ParentId == parentId);

Comment: As the entities have different names for the parent properties, I'd have to implement the interfaces explicitly in most of the entities, so the code I save in the repository would be moved to the entity. I do not want to follow that path. What I want to do is to change `Func<TEntity, TParentKey> ParentKeySelector` to `Expression<Func<TEntity, TParentKey> ParentKeySelector>` and do whatever expression magic needed to make the Contains work without evaluating the `IQueryable<TEntity>`.